# NETBEANS: “java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space”

Tags: java, netbeans, heap-memory

I encountered an error in Netbeans:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

This is the first time I encountered this and I don't know how to deal with it.

Can somebody explain this error message to me?

And how can I increase the heap memory? Thank you!

Comment: I think @Jens is right , yes that question can this answer too..

Comment: yeah, I saw that link already. But having too many answers make me confused that's why I asked new one. But anyways, thank you. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set it in NetBeans ide in the project properties -> Run -> VM options

Right click on your project "Properties"
Select "Run" category.
Enter your arguments(-Xmx512m) in the "VM Options" text box.
Example: Putting -Xmx512m in the "VM Options" text box gives 512Mb maximum heap size to your Java program.

Answer (score 3):

It could be an error related to Netbeans itself, then consider launching Netbeans with `-Xmx` key as it is described here: https://performance.netbeans.org/howto/jvmswitches/

Also it could be related to your particular project, you are trying to launch in Netbeans. In this case open project properties, go to `Run` section and extend memory for your project via `-Xmx` switch in `VM Options` as it is shown below:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Rafael, thank you for your answer. Do I have to restart my netbeans after I modified the VM Options? Because I've tried to modified it as Viraj instructed but nothing happens. Thanks again.

Comment: @nhix if you have changed Netbeans startup options, you need to restart Netbeans. If you have modified project options, restart your project. In case restarting your project did not help, modify Netbeans startup options to provide more memory to VM and restart Netbeans. If changing memory settings does not help, consider providing more memory to Netbeans/Your project, seems that volume you provided is not enough.

Comment: Hi @Rafael, thank you very much for your support and help. My problem is now fixed. I really appreciate your help. Thank you. ;)